# Is there a way to INDEX / ARRAY certain multiple (non adjacent) columns from a range?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, indexing, google-sheets-formula, multiple-columns

I have a calculated and filtered range that produces over a hundred columns. However I only want to show a handful.

```
=INDEX(FILTER(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NLj6NBgU2z2V2ZKjr6-tRjITpYU9E5XOoklqTCEFrPo","Database!$B$2:$JT$1943")
,
(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NLj6NBgU2z2V2ZKjr6-tRjITpYU9E5XOoklqTCEFrPo",Tracker!B15)=Tracker!B16)
+
(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NLj6NBgU2z2V2ZKjr6-tRjITpYU9E5XOoklqTCEFrPo",Tracker!B15)=Tracker!B15))
,,7)
```

The formula looks pretty complicated and long but it's just a standard filter with two possible correct solutions - I'm just pulling the data from another sheet. It filters down over 1400 rows based on variables. Then out of that filtered range it indexes the selected column.

It currently *only* shows column 7, but I am looking for it show **column 7, 255, 261, 256, 266, 262.** In that order.

Is there a way to do this? I have had a look around and can't seem to find the Syntax. Happy to use solutions that change the original formula completely but *please bear in mind, I am looking to use **SORT** function eventually on the whole INDEX formula.*

Thanks in advance.

Example sheet to play around with;

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gj1E2lLPOz-kbGw4qB-fx9VhefN1vFbEiQHY57NaNSo/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I would suggest wrapping the first importrange in a query() function and set the condition in the "where-clause". This will also allow you to sort the result.  [LINK](https://productivityspot.com/query-function-google-sheets/).

Comment: Could you give an example of the QUERY syntax to retrieve the specific columns? I am not well versed on QUERY syntax.

Comment: A lot of unkowns in the infromation you shared. E.g: what's in Tracker!B15 (second parameter of the second and third importrange. Best would be to share a copy of your spreadsheet (sensitive data erased) so we can get a better understanding of what you want to achieve.

Comment: OK, thanks. I have updated with a link to an example copy sheet. Some cell references have changed in the formula but it is still pulling from the original database sheet.

Comment: Is B15 a named range? I would expect a sheetname + range as the second paramater of importrange?

Comment: Yes it is a named range. I did that so I can cycle through the ranges in a drop-down list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the tab 'JPV_HELP' I entered in cell C3

```
=IF($B$15="None","-",
QUERY(
IMPORTRANGE(
"https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NLj6NBgU2z2V2ZKjr6-tRjITpYU9E5XOoklqTCEFrPo",
"Database!$B$2:$JT$1943"), 
"Select Col7, Col255, Col261, Col256, Col266 , Col262 
where Col266 matches '"&textjoin("|", 1, B15:B16)&"'", 1)
)
```

If you want to sort by a certain column you can include that in the query.

```
"Select Col7, Col255, Col261, Col256, Col266 , Col262 
where Col266 matches '"&textjoin("|", 1, B15:B16)&"' order by Col7 asc"
```

Use 'desc' instead of 'asc' of you want to sort descending.

See if that works for you?

Comment: That works perfectly! thanks so much. Would there be a way to make that sort addition dynamic? So I could change the column to sort by with a drop-down list for example?

Comment: Sure you can do  " order by Col7 "&IF(B22, "asc", "desc") ". Also see the formula in the spreadsheet where I applied the same logic.

Comment: Just had a few tweaks with it, I'm afraid it doesn't work if I wanted change the filter by in B:15 to Industry. or Exchange etc. I think it is due to the "where Col266 matches" constraint. As that is the 'Sector' named range in the Database. Is there a way to have the "where ColX matches" dynamic. So that if B:15 shows 'Industry' it would say "where Col262 matches". If it helps Col: 262=Industry, 266=Sector, 256=Currency, 261=Market.
Let me know if it is possible, and thanks for your help thus far

Comment: That should be possible. I have tried to add that in the formula. See if that helps?

Comment: That is it now. Thanks a bunch.